# Does git checkout branch command actually really compare against remote?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

my project currently have two branch, `master` and `feature`, and I working on `feature` branch.

When I'm done, I have performed git push to `bitbucket` and perform `pull request` at `bitbucket` dashboard.

Now that everything has done, I head back to my terminal, I am still at `feature` branch, so what I do is `git checkout master` to switch back to `master`, and I get the message

> Switched to branch 'master'
>
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'

I thought this means that my local workspace is actually updated and synced with remote origin, but then it's wrong because I ran `git pull` and I get below

```
remote: Counting objects: 1, done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
From https://git.domain.com:1234/bitbucket/xx/xx
   256c6bc..0a3bb4f  master    -> origin/master
Updating 256c6bc..0a3bb4f
Fast-forward
 .eslintrc.js                  |  15 +-
 App/Containers/xx.js | 363 ++++++++++++++++++------------------
 App/Containers/xxa.js  | 594 +++++++++++++++++------------------------------------------
 3 files changed, 352 insertions(+), 620 deletions(-)
```

At this point I kinda think there's no magic and `master` branch will not magically being the same as remote origin, and hence I will need to `git pull`.

1. Wondering if my understanding is correct?
2. At the earlier stage, when I first switched back to `master` after performing the merge, isn't the message `Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'` kinda misleading?

Comment: A fact that's a little mind-blowing for people new to Git: `origin/master` *is* local! It's just that when you run `git fetch`, your Git calls up the other Git at `origin`, collects anything new, copies it over to your local Git, and then updates your (local) `origin/master` to remember the `master` it saw in that other Git.

Comment: Meanwhile, `git pull` means: *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command.* The second Git command is useful because all `git fetch` did was collect new commits and update your `origin/*` names. Now that you have the updated commits, you may want to *do something* with or about them, and that takes a second Git command. I advise beginners to avoid `git pull` though, because ... what second command do you want to run? If you're not *sure* yet, don't let `git pull` pick one for you.

Comment: Moreover, both the `git fetch` *and* the second command can *fail*, and it's good  learn about this before you let `git pull` run two commands, have one of them fail, and leave you in the dark about where to look to even begin cleaning up the mess left behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part is that in `git` there are really 3 "copies" of any branch:

1. The copy on the local machine
2. The copy of the remote on the local machine
3. The copy on the remote machine

When `git status` tells you "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'", it is comparing #1 and #2. Performing `git fetch` is how #2 is updated to match #3.

In short, you're correct that there is no magic. On your machine `origin/master` is not automatically kept up-to-date with the actual remote.

Comment: Now it explains everything from your answer! Just a lil confusion with the statement **Performing git fetch is how #2 is updated to match #3**. Shouldn't it be from #3 to #2 instead?

Comment: @Isaac I think we're saying the same thing, #2 is changed so that it is the same as #3 - ie #2 is updated from #3

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

Git operations like `git status`, `git checkout`, `git commit` are all performed offline, using the data in your Git repository.

What you want to do to know if your branch is really up to date with the remote is to start with a `git fetch`. This will retrieve the data from the remote server and update `origin/master` and the other branches on origin.

Afterwards, `git status` will tell you your branch is out-of-date with the origin.

**My 2 cents on `git pull`**

I'm not a fan of `git pull`, because you don't really know ahead of time what it's going to do: simplifying a bit, it is more-or-less equivalent to doing `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, but with only automated checks in between.

I much prefer this workflow:

- `git fetch`
- analyze the results looking at the log from `git fetch`, as well as `git status` and/or `git log` and/or `git diff`
- `git merge` or `git rebase`, or even sometimes `git pull`, depending on my analysis, possibly with a temporary dev branch or a `git stash`

My workflow is more work than a straight `git pull`, but I know what's going to happen before any changes are made.

Answer (score 0):

At that moment, `Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'` is shown as expected. But during the period until a next fetch/pull, the `master` in the remote repository might be updated by the pull requests of yours or others, and new commits might be created due to non-fast-forward merge. As a result, your local `master`(and `origin/master`) will be several commits behind the `master` in the remote repository. `git pull` will get the new commits to update `origin/master` and `master`.

Comment: `But during the period until a next fetch/pull, the master in the remote repository might be updated by the pull requests of yours or others`, this scenario I understand, however it doesn't apply to my case because I am sure there's nobody commit in between, and I witnessed it within seconds also

Comment: @Isaac I guess your local master was diverged from the master that was going to accept your pull request. If so, the master in the origin repository had been updated by others since your last fetch/pull.

Comment: Nope because I'm the only user in the repo, that's why I was confused too

Comment: @Isaac you can check the commits by `git log 256c6bc..0a3bb4f` and try to find out by who, in which pull request, when and how they are created and pushed.